# Why do Kollelim have only half a day on Fast Days?

Tags: torah-study, fast-days, yeshiva-school

Why does BMG in Lakewood close the Yeshiva in the afternoon of a ta'anis like I witnessed on Asarah Ba'teives? Since when are people so weak that it has become seemingly impossible to learn on a fast day? Shouldn't those who learn Torah all day have to put in at least as much effort as those who work and are able to fast a whole day while working?

Comment: `Since when are people so weak that it has become seemingly impossible to learn on a fast day` Is this a rant, or an actual question? If the latter consider toning down the language. Designing a schedule isn't a statement that other schedules are nearly impossible.

Comment: `Shouldn't those who learn Torah all day have to put in at least as much effort as those who work and are able to fast a whole day while working` Evidently the people making the schedule, don't feel bound to mimic the experience of people working in other settings. Why should they even be correlated?

Comment: The tag yeshiva policies that you used, seems primarily designed for off topic questions. I would delete it. As I [mention on meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/delete-yeshiva-policies-tag).

Comment: @mevaqesh. Of course they are correlated. Toraso umanuso. And all the more so if the wives are out working a full day and still fasting.

Comment: Remember to always edit any information that you believe to be relevant, into the post itself.

Comment: I know many people who rest the afternoon as it's difficult to concentrate. But rest assured they make up the lost hours that night. At work that wouldn't be possible

Comment: Why is it weird that a Jewish institution follows a schedule that's convenient for Jews? Should they instead follow a "regular worker's" schedule and have off on Christmas and Martin Luther King Jr. day?

Answer (score 3):

Given that some people fast well and others not so well, by not having an official kollel session in the afternoon, they are giving people the choice - presumably those who can learn, do so. A husband may need to lend a hand at home if his wife isn't feeling so good too. Someone who rests in the afternoon will probably be able to learn more that evening anyway.

In Israel, many religious settings (work, schools, etc.) have half or shortened days on a fast day. If everyone could have the afternoon off on a fast day, that would be the ideal, but, of course, in the regular working world it isn't usually possible. Usually when religious people can make schedules independent of outside demands, they can do so with what is more convenient/ appropriate to religious people in mind. Why shouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for every yeshivah. But, in my neighborhood, on many fast days, esp. during the summer, a number of the rebbes, roshei yeshivot, etc. are invited to speak at community events and other *shiurim*.

I can't say whether that's a "fair" way to allocate their resources or not. But, I assume that there are enough non-working people around in the community to warrant having them speak at these places such that the communal needs outweigh keeping these people in the yeshiva the rest of the day for the students.